# Is /etc/aliases the only file defining where root mails are redirected?

Tags: linux, email, root, alias

My school has a server with the file /etc/aliases. This file notably contains the line `root:someuser` (it is the only line with the key `root`).

Does it mean that every mail sent to root@hostname.com is redirected to and **only to** someuser@hostname.com?

Since someuser@hostname.com isn't receiving mail it would mean that all root mails are simply lost, am I correct?

Also, we use sendmail.

Comment: I think this depends on how your school set up their system.

Comment: @john is correct. There is no way to tel without knowing the config. There are certainly files other then /etc/aliases that can (but don't have to) play a much bigger role in delivery.  (Also, are to sure they are using sendmail? It's certainly possible but Postfix is a common drop in replacement which is superior in most ways and includes the sendmail command.